# How to limit http response time in php

Tags: php, function, http-headers

I'm using some sites to detect my site visitor's country. I mean like this

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  
$url1 = 'http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php?ip='.$ip;
$url2 = 'http://ip2country.sourceforge.net/ip2c.php?format=JSON&ip='.$ip;
```

Sometimes sites like sourgeforge taking too much time to load.

So can anyone tell how to limit the http response time.?

if `url1` is down or not responded in `x seconds` then move to `url2,url3,etc`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$context  = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'GET',
      , 'timeout' => 3 
    )
));
```

Then supply the stream context to fopen() or file_get_contents() etc...

http://php.net/manual/en/stream.contexts.php
http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php

The manual calls that a "read timeout". I worry it may not include time for stuff like dns resolution + socket connection. I think the timeout before php tries reading from the stream may be governed by the [default_socket_timeout](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.default-socket-timeout) setting.

You may want to consider curl, it seems a bit more specific, but I'm not sure if `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` is inclusive of `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT`.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Answer (score 2):

If this is done using streams, you could use [`stream_set_timeout`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php) for this. A decent example from the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-timeout.php), it also describes more advanced ways of archieving this:

```
$fp = fsockopen("www.example.com", 80);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "Unable to open\n";
} else {

    fwrite($fp, "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n");
    stream_set_timeout($fp, 2);
    $res = fread($fp, 2000);

    $info = stream_get_meta_data($fp);
    fclose($fp);

    if ($info['timed_out']) {
        echo 'Connection timed out!';
    } else {
        echo $res;
    }

}
```

Comment: THis looks real good if you make use of the connection timeout `$fp = fsockopen("www.example.com", 80, $_, $_, 2.0);`

Answer (score 1):

There is another solution, just download the DB and offer that service to yourself on a faster machine of your own:

[IP to Geolocation db](http://ip2country.sourceforge.net/faq.php#Sources_of_IP_Geolocation)